# DjangoCMS add childplugin button

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I have people `PeoplePlugin` that can have many of child plugins `PersonPlugin`. I want to add to edit mode a button (Add child plugin) to a template of `PeoplePlugin`, that allows me to open modal to create new 'PersonPlugin', the same way as in side-toolbar. Is that possible? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at `render_model_add` which allows you to create model instances; http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/templatetags.html#render-model-add

Comment: Just another note on this. The `render_model_add` is the feature you're looking for, but it's not designed for plugins. It's meant for your own models which are introduced via app hooks. It brings frontend editing to apps traditionally edited via the backend. With CMS plugins, if you're looking at a parent plugin, you can already switch to edit mode & access the placeholder to add the child with relative ease.

Comment: @markwalker_ Thank you very much! It works for me!

Comment: In that case, I'll write an answer explaining how it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django CMS provides a template tag designed to allow frontend editing of your models, usually integrated via app hooks within the CMS.

When it comes to creating model instances `{% render_model_add my_model %}` will render a `+` icon in the page ([docs](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/templatetags.html#render-model-add)), for example;

```
<h3>
    <a href="{{ my_model.get_absolute_url }}">{{ my_model.title }}</a>
    {% render_model_add my_model %}
</h3>
```

This would render a `h3` with a title of your model as a link to, lets assume, it's detail view. Then alongside that would be, when in edit mode, a `+` which you can double click to create an instance of `my_model`. If you don't like the `+` icon you can also use [`render_model_add_block`](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/templatetags.html#render-model-add-block) which allows custom markup to form the link to the add form.

This is perfect for models within apps, but if used for plugins can be problematic because this simple implementation wouldn't create a plugin with a link to a placeholder or potentially the other things you get when creating a plugin via placeholders.

Another element that brings frontend editing to your models is `{% render_model my_model "attr" %}` ([docs](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/templatetags.html#render-model)) which will render the attribute of that model instance in the context to users, and if you're in edit mode, allow you to double click on it to edit the object.

An example of this kind of editing, would be a contact info model;

```
{% render_model_block contact_info %}
    <h2>{{ instance.contact_modal_heading }}</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <strong>Phone:</strong> <a href="tel:{{ instance.phone }}">{{ instance.phone }}</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <strong>Email:</strong> <a href="mailto:{{ instance.email }}">{{ instance.email }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endrender_model_block %}

<div>
    {% render_placeholder contact_info.contact_content 500 %}
</div>
```